# File compressor with recovery

Tags: data-recovery, compression, checksum, crc

I want to compress a lot of files with a file compressor. I've found that 7z is really good at this stuff, but the problem is that it doesn't add CRC recovery to the file to prevent corrumption in the files.

RAR archive does it actually, but I would prefer use 7z.

Is there any solution?

Thanks!

PS: I know the existence of par2 but I would like not to split the compressed file and the parity file. I would like them merged into the same file, as RAR can do.

Comment: I am not aware of any other solution except for PAR2.  However, those tools have long been abandoned, sounds like you need to use a different compression tool that supports 7z compression other than your current tool.

Comment: Does anyone know one?

Comment: won't that just tell you if it is corrupted - rather than prevent it ? (although I'm thinking more of bit-rot here)

Comment: @Smock - The entire point of PAR2 files is to be able to run those files up against your achieve and potentially fix the corrupted blocks in the archive file.  However, how many corrupted blocks can exist, depends on the amount of PAR2 files you generate.  Of course once you talk about combining that functionality into a single file, you have to be able to repair the entire file, which presents it's own problems.

Comment: @Ramhound so you recommend to use par2 and create separate parity files, isn't it?